# Execute PE from memory

Tags: c, parsing, portable-executable, dynamic-library, entry-point

I tried to write LoadLibrary function in C.
The function gets a path to a DLL file which, normally, pops up message box when it loads (I tried to run that DLL file using the original LoadLibrary function and it works).

Basically, the DLL content is loaded into a buffer, parsed and runs from entry point.

In `VirtualAllocEx` function, I use `PAGE_READWRITE` protection mode. Then, when running the line `f(nth->OptionalHeader.ImageBase, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, NULL)`, I get the following error message: `Exception thrown at 0x10011032 in PE.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x10011032.` (0x10011032 is entry point address).

If I change the mode to `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`, the error message is: `Exception thrown at 0x00019644 in PE.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00019644.` (No idea what is that address).

I think that it's clear why it's not smart to allow execution in all sectors of the PE, but I did it for testing purposes only. In the final code, I'll need to write it properly.

My code is attached.
(BTW, if you have other suggestions that are not related to my question - I'll glad to know).

```
#include <Windows.h>

typedef HMODULE func(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved);

HMODULE LoadLibraryFromMem(char* dllPath)

{
    DWORD read;
    HANDLE handle;
    handle = CreateFileA(dllPath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    DWORD size = GetFileSize(handle, NULL);
    PVOID vDll = VirtualAlloc(NULL, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    BOOL r = ReadFile(handle, vDll, size, &read, NULL);
    CloseHandle(handle);
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosh = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)vDll;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nth = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((PBYTE)vDll + dosh->e_lfanew);
    handle = GetCurrentProcess();
    PVOID vImg = VirtualAllocEx(
        handle,
        nth->OptionalHeader.ImageBase,
        nth->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage,
        MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
        PAGE_READWRITE
    ); // HERE --> PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE
    WriteProcessMemory(
        handle,
        vImg,
        vDll,
        nth->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders,
        0
    );
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sech = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(nth);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nth->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
        WriteProcessMemory(
            handle,
            (PBYTE)vImg + sech[i].VirtualAddress,
            (PBYTE)vDll + sech[i].PointerToRawData,
            sech[i].SizeOfRawData,
            0
        );
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR impd = nth->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + nth->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;

    HANDLE proc;
    while (((PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)impd)->Name)
    {
        LPSTR dllName = (nth->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + ((PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)impd)->Name);
        HMODULE dllAdr = LoadLibraryA(dllName);
        PDWORD iat = nth->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + ((PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)impd)->FirstThunk;

        while (*iat)
        {
            LPSTR funcName = ((PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)(nth->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + *iat))->Name;
            proc = GetProcAddress(dllAdr, funcName);
            if (!proc)
                return NULL;
            impd->FirstThunk = proc;
            iat++;
        }
        impd++;
    }
    func* f = (func*)(nth->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + nth->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint);
    f(nth->OptionalHeader.ImageBase, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    LoadLibraryFromMem("mydll.dll");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is more in a DLL than loading and memory protection... Are you doing the reloactions? And the fixing the import entry points?

Comment: About the import table, of course, you can see the procedure in the while loop. About the relocations, there's no need to relocate for now, because the DLL is loaded to the same address as in the PE (`OptionalHeader.ImageBase`).

Comment: Shouldn't `impd->FirstThunk = proc;` be intead `*iat = proc` or something like that? Because you are not changing `impd` in the inner loop, so you are writing on the same address many times!

Comment: You're right! it should be `*iat =proc`! Now it runs perfectly. But I still have to set the permission to `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` - which is not safe. How should I write it correctly?

Comment: Well, to be really safe, you'll have to split the image into its sections. That is, `.text` will be `PAGE_EXECUTE` or `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`, `.rsrc` and `.rdata` should be ``PAGE_READONLY`, `.idata` could be mapped `PAGE_READWRITE` and then changed to `PAGE_READONLY` once you are done linking...